# About update performance in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

```
tb_users 
 id (pk)
 login_name

tb_test
 id (pk)
 user_id
 user_code
```

The sample date is like below

```
tb_users (id, login_name)    
11e8, tom
11e3, jerry
11e1, peter
   ...  49316 more items

tb_test (id,user_id,user_code)
ff3f10b01, ,tom
ff3f10b02, ,tom
ff3f10b03, ,tom 
ff3f10b04, ,peter
  ...  70000 more items
```

Now I need to update field 'user_id' in tb_test with 'id' in tb_user. I wrote the sql.

```
update tb_test a
   set a.user_id = (select b.id
                      from tb_user b
                     where a.user_code = b.login_name )
```

It takes more than 1 minute! I wrote the select sql, it runs very fast.
How should I improve the update efficiency?

```
select a.*, b.id
 from tb_test a, tb_user b
where a.user_code = b.login_name
```

The result should be like this

```
tb_test (id,user_id,user_code)
ff3f10b01, 11e8 ,tom
ff3f10b02, 11e8 ,tom
ff3f10b03, 11e8 ,tom 
ff3f10b04, 11e1 ,peter
  ...  70000 more items
```

Comment: There's are reasons we call it 'sample' data, one of which is that enquirers aren't compelled to provide unreadable strings like 'ff3f10b0-8b14-11e8-bd12-898e8aca406e'

Comment: How can Tom, Jerry and Peter have the same `id` ? This is PK

Comment: @Cid the id the two tables is GUID

Comment: @Strawberry 'ff3f10b0-8b14-11e8-bd12-898e8aca406e' is GUID

Comment: The relation ship between two tables is user_code = login_name

Comment: @Ian I know what a GUID is, but this is an unique index constraint violation

Comment: Sure, but it's irrelevant. For the purposes of the problem,it could just as well be 'a406e'

Comment: @Strawberry the update performance is very low

Comment: This looks like a one-off data cleanup exercise, am I right? (i.e. you're replacing the user_code with user_id (which is the correct thing on which to join your tables). So you won't be doing this often, I think? Therefore who cares really if it takes a few minutes? You could probably improve it by using a proper JOIN but does it matter that much?

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: @ADyson, in fact I will do it everyday. It is very low efficient for updating in large volume records. I think I find another way to do it

Comment: why will you do it every day? If you find yourself doing this every day, a better solution would be to fix your schema properly and fix whatever is writing into this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend writing this as a `join`:

```
update tb_test t join
       tb_user u
       on t.user_code = u.login_name
   set t.user_id = u.id;
```

Then, for performance, you want an index on `tb_user(login_name, id)`.

That said, you are updating almost all rows.  In many cases, it is cheaper just to recreate the table:

```
create table temp_tb_test as
    select t.id, u.id as user_id, t.user_code
    from tb_test t left join
         tb_user u
         on t.user_code = u.login_name;

truncate table tb_test;  -- be very cautious here!

insert into tb_test(id, user_id, user_code)
    select id, user_id, user_code
    from temp_tb_test;
```

Comment: thanks for you suggestion. you give me another approach. yes, insert is much better than update. I try to get and handle the results in js (code level) and then use delete and insert sql. It is good now.